# variance of a Maximum Liklihood estimator

Tags: estimation, variance, maximum-likelihood

I am reading a book on Bayesian Estimation and Sensor Fusion and I want to know where the formula below come from. 
In fact, what is the relation between the variance and the second derivative of the ML estimation?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the variance of a weighted sum of independent RVs (in a slightly odd form)

If:
$$
\hat{x}=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k x_k
$$

where the $X_k, k=1\dots n$ are independent RVs then:

$$
\mbox{Var}(\hat{X})=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k^2 \mbox{Var}(X_k)
$$

But: $\alpha_k=\frac{\partial \hat{x}}{\partial x_k}$

Comment: Merci beaucoup.